# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE memory needed

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

How much memory needed to run ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE without killing other activities in task?

With DDMS I've seend that there is 2,5-3 Mb free memory in heap, but sometimes Android kills my activity which calls ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sometimes Android kills my activity which calls ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

That's a fully expected thing on Android. The OS may kill any activity that is in the background (invisible for user). That's why you need to implement your activity in accordance to Activity life-cycles. Check the guide on this: [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle). If you properly save/restore the state of the activity, then you are on a safe side - your calling activity (which calls ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) will be fully restored for you when user comes back to it from Camera activity.

Comment: My application has the StarterActivity which chooses activity to run according with current application state that stored on server. And current activity (RegisterActivity) is not stored, so Starter cannot run it directly. So, I have only way to make my registration activity immortal

Comment: @skayred: it sounds really odd, a previously killed by OS activity **should** be restored for you by the OS.